# Datatable rows select operation showing error when column name has special characters. (C#)

Tags: c#, syntax, datatables, msdn, escaping

I am trying to perform select operation on a datatable to extract some values from a column.
The column that I am targeting has some special characters in it.
so the error message is saying,

```
An exception has occured: Cannot interpret token ']' at position
```

the syntax that I am using is this,

```
DataRow[] DataRows = dataSet.Tables["ParentTable"].Select("[ColumnName[somText]]");
```

I have referred the docs, where they talk about the use of escape sequences in these type of cases, here is the link to that particular section

([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#:~:text=If%20a%20column%20name%20contains%20any%20non%2Dalphanumeric%20characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=If%20a%20column%20name%20contains%20any%20non%2Dalphanumeric%20characters))

let me know your solutions.

Comment: do you mean your column name has `[` `]`?

Comment: ColumnName[somText] <= this is my column name

Comment: example: StudentsName[en-in]

Comment: you tag question with `linq`, do you really want linq solution? `DataTable.Select` isn't linq.

Comment: I'll remove the `linq` tag 

Comment: try `Select(@"[ColumnName[somText\]]")`

Comment: Thank you It worked!!!, if possible, please share the link where I can learn more about this syntax!

Comment: the doc you shared already said. you just escape the enclosing ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion from Lei Yang, worked!

```
Select(@"[ColumnName[somText\]]")
```

you can read more about it  [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0#:%7E:text=If%20a%20column%20name%20contains%20any%20non%2Dalphanumeric%20characters)